# What happens if I Wick contract a trace operator internally?

Tags: supersymmetry, yang-mills, propagator, wick-theorem, trace

In theories such as $\cal{N}=4$ supersymmetric Yang-Mills, we often consider operators such as $\cal{O}(x_1)=$Tr$(\phi(x_1)\phi(x_1))$, with $\phi$ the scalar field(s) of the theory. Then we go on calculating expectation values. But what happens if I Wick contract the two fields in the trace together to get a sort of bubble diagram? In $\cal{N}=4$ SYM, the propagator of $\phi$ is given by:

$$\langle \phi(x) \phi(y) \rangle \sim (x-y)^{-2}, \tag{1}$$

which means that the contraction I mentioned above would be $\infty$. In the notes of my professor, he never mentions such diagrams and go on calculating the other ones, so I imagine that they are either zero for some reason, or we drop them out, maybe because it is considered as a vacuum infinity.

Any suggestion?

Comment: After some reading, it seems that it is the normal ordering that discards the self-contractions. So I guess it would then be part of the vacuum infinity. Anybody to confirm this thought?